# Visio C# DoubleClick

Tags: c#, visio, double-click

I have implemented double-Click on my Visio standalone program using this:

http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Handling-the-Double-Click-Event-with-the-Visio-API.aspx

But since I started using mouseUp, it stopped working. Anyone have some C# sample code that can show me how I can use "double mouseUp" to implement doubleClick?Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution :)

```
    private DateTime firstClick = DateTime.Now;

    private void axDrawingControl1_MouseUpEvent(object sender, AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.EVisOcx_MouseUpEvent e)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now < firstClick.AddMilliseconds(SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime))
        {
            ShapeDoubleClick(sender, e);
        }

        firstClick = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Rodrigo